# Using Javascript, how can I scale an element relative to the center of a viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, geometry, transform

I'm essentially trying to produce a very simple Google Maps clone.

I have a div with a fairly complex layout on it, which I want to scale and drag around. I'm using the [Pep](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js/) library for drag and drop, and using CSS `transform: scale()` for the zoom.

My problem is that the `transform-origin` point should always be the centre of the viewport. It's fine when the scale is at the default level of 1, but when it's something different it doesn't seem to work.

I have a reduced test case going [in a codepen](http://codepen.io/jodi/pen/AlFCb), where I've set a small box to be a visual representation of the `transform-origin` point. This should ideally be staying in the middle of the viewport at all times.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still open question:
You have to calculate shift from viewport point to top left, scale and shift back, or in other words scale viewport as well.
Otherwise You are scaling from old viewport or from the origin.
If you like I can rewrite it without viewport.

Comment: Hi EvilJS. Thank you, I've since managed to solve it for my specific use case.

Comment: @JodiWarren mind to share your solution here?

Comment: @ThorbenCroisé I originally posted almost 8 years ago, I'm afraid I don't have the memory (or code) to reference. I do apologise, I hate coming across those vague messages and I'm embarassed to have left one.